# Is there a way to store math functions (used to describe curves) in json?

Tags: javascript, json, eval

I'd like to store various curves in json, and of course those aren't native data types. I hesitate to use the word "function", I'm not talking about javascript functions.

If, for instance, I wanted to store the horizontal line at y=2, I might have written it out in highschool as `f(x) = 2`, or if I wanted the exponential it could be `f(x) = 2**x`.

Of course, to make use of the data (rather than to just display it as the raw string to a human), at some point this would need to be parsed and turned into javascript possible.

Is there a clever way to do this, so as to avoid the pitfalls of eval()? It seems like maybe that the only alphabetic characters that should even be allowed in the string are 'f','x', and 'y' anyway, everything else should be math operators and parentheses. But then I remembered that I'd probably at some point want trig.

Some of these will be user-supplied, and I don't know the expected volume. Nor will they only ever be used client-side.

Comment: I think what you need isn't completely clear.  You could use an math equation parsing library and send those equations as strings.  Or describe the equations as an AST encoded in JSON, and then parse that tree structure in the client to do math.  Is that what you need?

Comment: @Amy I need a way to describe these and pass them as json without it being some absurd number of x,y pairs, which wouldn't even represent what I want very well (at least for n pairs n < 300). I was hoping this was a solved problem I was too dull to figure out how to google.

Comment: Neither if my suggestions involves an absurd number of pairs.